# Event that would listen to any label click in form

Tags: c#, onclick, label

Well, I'm making a chess game that's based on labels. I need to listen for label click, so when user clicks on an label, I get the name of label he clicked. I know I can do it for each label, but is there an universal event that would help me do the same thing for all of them in one event / loop?

Comment: You can assign one event to multiple labels same time in the properties of VS forms designer. You can parse by code labels of a Controls list of a control (a form or a panel for example) and assign whose are labels you want the same delegate. What do you want to do?

Comment: Well, I'm not perfect in English, but I'll try to explain. I need one event that would trigger when user clicks on any label, and that event would tell me the name of label user clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have taken 64 labels.

---

In windows form, on click event of Label1 you will write following code:

---

```
private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = sender as Label;
    MessageBox.Show(label.Name);
}
```

---

For remaining 63 Lables, In Design view, select all 63 lables by using Ctrl key --> Go to Property window --> Under Event option select Click option --> From dropdownlist select 'Label1_Click' option.

---

Just finish & run the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/group-controls-with-wf-panel-control-using-the-designer)
 structure to group your labels and then call the desired event on that Panel, so it will trigger whenever you click one of it's elements.

Another solution would be to identify your label with the coordinates of the mouse click (the amount of code that requires depends how you placed them of course).

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments you can assign one event to all...

```
 List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();

 foreach (var lbl in lbls)
 {
     lbl.Click += lbl_Click;
 }

 void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Label lbl = sender as Label;

     MessageBox.Show(lbl.Name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign these methods to every label you need to manage in the VS form designer (you go to events of controls, at the click line and select the method in the list instead of double click on it):

```
private void Label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var nameLabel = ( sender as Label )?.Name ?? "Error";
  // ...
}

private void Label_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ( sender as Label ).Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void Label_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ( sender as Label ).Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Cursor change added for convenience if you want.

If you want to dynamically assign events, you can use the @caner answer, and you can group all in a panel to parse Panel.Controls and assign event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom label class that inherits from `Label`. You can then subscribe to the `Click` event of the base class and do your thing.

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public MyLabel()
    : base()
    {
        Click += ProcessClickEvent;
    }

    private void ProcessClickEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what you want to do
    }
}
```